# TSQL concatenation of multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to concatenate 7 columns from a table into a single column called scan_data.

I know there is a concatenate option in SQL, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: If the columns are so similar that you need to concatenate them, why do you use multiple columns at all? Use another table with two columns, the foreign-key to the first table and another `DataType` columnto differentiate the type. On that way all of your queries are getting much easier and more efficient. That process is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: The data in the columns was from a single string then parsed out into different fields. Now I need to get them all back into a single string in the same table.

Comment: The title and the question are asking different things. Do you want to concatenate *columns* or *rows*?

Comment: Seriously? There are 5 good results to a google search for sql concatenation: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+concatenation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Sql Server 2012 or newer, just use the [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function:

```
select scan_data = concat(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7)
from MyTable
```

For versions before Sql Server 2012, you'll need to use:

```
select scan_data = column1 + column2 + column3 + column4 + column5 + column6 + column7
from MyTable
```

If any of your columns contains null values, you'll need to null-guard them (ie `isnull(column1, '')`) or the entire concatenated string will return null. **Only the pre-2012 version requires null-guarding - `concat` takes care of that for you.**